# Python server client socket

Tags: python, sockets

I've tried to connect two computers with a socket in Python and I don't know why it doesn't work. The files are from internet and it compiles for me but without any results.

The server.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python           

import socket               

s = socket.socket()       
host = '' 
port = 12345                
s.bind((host, port))        

s.listen(5)                 
while True:
    c, addr = s.accept()     
    print 'Got connection from', addr
    c.send('Thank you for connecting')
    c.close()
```

and the client.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python           

import socket               

s = socket.socket()         
host = # here I put the ip of the server's laptop
port = 12345                

s.connect((host, port))
print s.recv(1024)
s.close()
```

What's wrong?

Comment: This won't work, because there's a syntax error in the code. Anyhow, where is that code from? I'm asking because it is for old Python 2, and probably outdated.

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_networking.htm it's from here.

Comment: What _results_ are you expecting? BTW, you can try replacing `send` with `sendall`.

Comment: After fixing indentations and using localhost, this code worked for me. Are you saying nothing printed? You should have gotten an error exception at the least.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt the socket API has been stable for decades. This code works for 2.x and 3.x, as long as the _print_ statement is updated.

Comment: I know that the issues are miniscule, @tdelaney, but it still suggests that the tutorial is outdated. If you look around a bit, you will find lots of ads, a 10$ download for the PDF and all that for a tutorial obviously based on Python 2.4. This is a tutorial to avoid! Instead, use https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html and a contemporary Python version.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt - the example in the current docs is basically identical to the code shown here so I don't see how you get to "outdated".

Comment: The problem with simple examples in tutorials is that they tend to ignore things that can go wrong. You may have a firewall issue that would make the connect hang for a long time. Try adding `s.settimeout(5)` to the client code just before the connect. If the connect request is dropped on the server side, you'll see timeout error after 5 seconds.

Comment: The tutorial is outdated because it doesn't contain anything since roughly Python 2.4 or so while Python 3 has been out for **ages**. No context managers, no else after loops, just to name two important examples. If you don't care for your code's quality, it's fine to program using the smallest subset of a language that gets you going, but it should be the task of a tutorial to give an overview of a language's capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

You have to run the server first. Then run the client **at the same time**  with the IP of the server (I used localhost because it was running on one computer, maybe you should try if that works). The code worked fine for me, every time I ran the client, the server printed a message. If it doesn't work for you, maybe your firewall is not letting you open ports.

Just for the future, please always post any error messages you see.

BTW, isn't this the Python Documentation example for sockets?

Comment: I think this better written as a comment than an answer. OP hasn't told us what went on. And it is very close to the simple examples in the doc.

Comment: I fixed all the indentation problems. I used the IP of the server (I am running on two computers) and is still not receveing any message.. But still, I'm not sure what did you mean by "run the client at the same time with the IP of the server", how's that, if I run the server first?